Works in GCC, MSVC error C3615: constexpr function 'GPSinfo_T::GPSinfo_T' cannot result in a constant expression
I've got a really simple C++ 20 struct with a constexpr ctor. Compiles and runs fine with GCC recent versions, but not MSVC 2022 with latest patches. Is the MSVC compiler incorrect, or have I missed something?
struct GPSinfo_T {
    char fixSources[6];
    constexpr GPSinfo_T() :
        fixSources("NNNNN")
    {};
};


Is all of the shown code needed to replicate the errors? It is a proper [mre]? Have you tried to remove variable-initializations one by one until the code builds? If you do, then add back one variable at a time to find out which one causes the problem.

Here's a MRE: demo (the only issue is the char array).

https://godbolt.org/z/45nrPd6fM

Using default member initializers resolves MSVC issue: https://godbolt.org/z/r4Mxf6naT

Alternatively you can use std::array: https://godbolt.org/z/xP5x78YqE

The only member causing the MSVC error is the char array fixSources, as you can see in this minimum reproducable example:
struct GPSinfo_T {
    char fixSources[6];
    constexpr GPSinfo_T() :
        fixSources("NNNNN")
    {};
};

int main() {
}

Live demo 1 (with error on MSVC).
I am not a language-lawyer and unsure which compiler is correct here.
But as @MarekR suggested, a possible workaround for MSVC is to use default Member initialization, as shown below (corresponds to the MRE above):
struct GPSinfo_T {
    char fixSources[6] = "NNNNN";
    constexpr GPSinfo_T() = default;
};

int main() {
}

Live demo 2 (all compilers accept).
Alternatively change fixSources to be a std::array<char, 6> and you'll be able to use member initialization list as in your original code.
